# Scala: How to access associated parameter values of a macro annotation in the macro implementation?

Tags: scala, macros, annotations, arguments, scala-macro-paradise

I am working with macro annotations ([link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)) that are part of the macro paradise of Scala.

In their example they use a macro annotation called `identity` which takes no parameters. However, the macro annotation I am trying to implement does require an argument:

```
@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class f(id: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro identityMacro.impl
}

object identityMacro extends App {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*) = {
    import c.universe._
    // how to access id here?
  }
}
```

My question: how can I access the value of `id` in the implementation of the `identityMacro.impl` macro? I have tried passing it as an extra argument to `macroTransform` but this does not work. I assume I have to access it via the Context?